# Why can I reposition a pointer given as an argument to a function but not reassign a new value to it after `realloc`?

Tags: c

In this question I'm referring to another stackoverflow question because I don't have enough points to comment it.

---

See: [Valgrind Reports Invalid Realloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458075/valgrind-reports-invalid-realloc)

**In short:** Why must the instruction `buffer = trim(buffer);` be written outside the function? Why can't it be written inside the function as `phrase = (char*)realloc(phrase, strlen(phrase)+1);`?

---

**In depth:** Assuimng I pass any pointer to a function - such as `const *str;` - then by executing `str++;` I can create a side effect and change the starting position of the string.

But why can't I just reassign another value to the function through dynamic memory management functions such as `malloc` and `realloc`?

Why can't I just set `str = (char*) realloc(str, strlen(str) + 1 * sizeof(char));`?

What makes this side effect different from the other one?
Couldn't I hypothetically just move `str` where ever I want to?

Comment: C is pass by value. The function doesn't have access to the char * variable of the caller, just a copy of it. You can change the value of a pointer(hopefully to a valid new value), but realloc requires a value that was returned by malloc/calloc/realloc, not just one that points somewhere - not even inside a dynamically allocated block

Comment: @AviBerger But if it is "pass by value", why can I create these side effects and just increment it (sorry I'm coming from Java programming)

Comment: The argument `phrase` in `trim` is strictly local to that function.  The caller doesn't see it.  Any changes to `phrase` from inside `trim` will be hidden from the caller.  That's why `trim` returns the new pointer value.  If it didn't, it would be lost when `trim` returns.

Comment: You can change the copy. That has no direct impact on the original. Java is different from C. I have a C programming mantra for you: "There is no such thing as a reference type. There is no such thing as a reference type."

Comment: realloc is a function that releases memory pointed to by ptr. If the memory to be released is stack memory, rather than managed memory, realloc doesn't work.  If you want to just COPY  str memory, use a different function.

Comment: @AviBerger @TomKarez @david Thanks a lot for your help guys!
I'm sorry but I still have huge difficulties wrapping my head around this.

If it is strictly a local copy - then why can I change it with an increment operation such that my changes are visible from the outside?

in example:
```C

static void sideEffect(char *str) {
  str++; // works fine! This instruction changes the actual value - not it's copy!
  str = (char*) malloc(strlen(str) + 1 * sizeof(char)); // doesn't work for some reason :(
}
```

Comment: @sueszli: `str` is a copy of whatever value was passed to the function `sideEffect`. Therefore, `str++` changes the value of the local copy, not the value of the original variable that was used to call the function `sideEffect`. The same applies to `str = (char*) malloc(strlen(str) + 1 * sizeof(char));`.

Comment: Java is also pass-by-value. Pass an `int` to a function, and if you change that value, the caller doesn't see the changes. `void test(char **str) { (*str)++; }` then assuming `char *fubar = "hello world"; test(&fubar);` ... have a play around with this. Also, K&R2e. Read it, do the exercises as you stumble across them...

Comment: I think perhaps a part of the confusion is seeing two distinct assignment operators: `++` and `=`, and expecting one of those to change the caller's world whilst the other doesn't...

Comment: In Java you have a variable that is connected to a dynamically allocated object. In C you deal directly with entities - that are not necessarily dynamically allocated. You can (but don't always) have handles to those entities. These are entities of their own, classified as pointers. In `sideEffect` str++ changes the local str (a pointer). It does not effect the entity that was passed to the fcn. It also does not change the buffer it points into, just where in that buffer it points.

Comment: @sueszli: [This demonstration program](https://godbolt.org/z/ed976s5av) may help you understand. As you can see, the value of the original variable retains its value, only the copy is being changed.

Comment: @autistic Woah you we're right - my initial assumption that I could even create a sideeffect with `str++` was wrong. I tried it again and realized  that - Thanks for the explaination.

Comment: @AviBerger - This contrast to Java really made me understand the differences. Thank you so much - now I really get it :)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Didn't know a browser compiler existed! Thanks for the demo. Really helpful!

Comment: @sueszli we can declare our arguments `T *fubar` instead of `T fubar` and then operate on `(*fubar)` rather than `fubar`. In your case, `T` is `char *` so `T *` is `char **`. We can use the same idiom for any type, so that the caller can see updates that we cause. `realloc` communicates this info via the return value (as the answer states), instead. I thought to explain this to clarify your beliefs about pass-by-value, as you seemed confused about that. As in Java, need to pass a reference type (by value, of course) for the caller to see updates upon that which an argument points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C passes **all** arguments by value. Look at the parameters of a called function like local variables of this function, initialized by copies of the arguments given by the caller.

We can "emulate" pass by reference, if we pass a *pointer*. By dereferencing the pointer, we can access the "referenced" object living outside the called function. But this pointer is still passed by value, meaning it is a copy of the argument, initializing the parameter.

*Note: The references of C++ and other languages are nothing else than pointers, under the hood. There are additional semantics, though. You might want to look at generated machine code.*

So you can do anything you want with that pointer in the parameter, overwrite it, increment or decrement it, even `NULL` it. This has no effect of the source of the pointer in the caller.

The problem of the question you link can be boiled down to:

```c
char* called(char* pointer)
{
    return realloc(pointer, /* some irrelevant value */);
}

void caller(void)
{
  char* buffer = malloc(/* some irrelevant value */);

  /* ignore returned pointer */ called(buffer);

  free(buffer); /* here Valgrind reports an error */
}
```

We need to differentiate multiple cases for `realloc()` here.

1. `realloc()` returns `NULL`, because there is not enough memory to satisfy the request. The former address is still valid.
2. `realloc()` returns the same address, because it can satisfy the request this way. Since returned and former address are equal, both are valid.
3. `realloc()` returns a new address. The former address is now invalid.

Of these, the third case is the common one, and it leads to the documented issue.

Because `buffer` in `caller()` is not changed by `called()`, simply because `called()` cannot access it, it still holds the former address. Now when `free()` is called with this invalid address, the error is detected.

To correct this error, `caller()` needs to use the returned value. The Right Way<sup>TM</sup> to do this is:

```c
void caller(void)
{
  char* buffer = malloc(/* some irrelevant value */);

  char* new_buffer = called(buffer);
  if (new_buffer != NULL) {
    buffer = new_buffer;
  } else {
    /* handle the re-allocation error, the address in buffer is still valid */
  }

  free(buffer);
}
```

An alternative is to pass the *pointer to `buffer`* to `called()` and let it modify `buffer` correctly. But this type of redirection often generates worse readable code. However, for a convenience function you might decide to go this route.

Comment: Wow thank you so much - this was such an eloquent answer and REALLY REALLY helped me understand why realloc behaves the way it does and why my mental model was wrong.